# Trouble in python if else statements with multiple variables

Tags: python, if-statement

Looking help with the code below, it seems that adding m_Time on the first if statement makes the program run incorrectly. Just looking at the first if statement, the rest works as intended. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

```
tick_Num = float(input("How many tickets are you buying? "))
day = input("What day do you want to watch the movie? Enter mon for Monday etc. ")
m_Time = int(input("What time is the movie? Enter 0000 to 2359: "))


if 200 <= m_Time <= 1600 and tick_Type == "child" and day != "sat" or day != "sun":
    print("You should be in school, not at the movies.")
elif tick_Type == "child" and day == "mon" or day == "tue" or day == "wed":
    total = 8 * tick_Num * 0.75
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "senior" and day == "mon" or day == "tue" or day == "wed":
    total = 9 * tick_Num * 0.75
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "general" and day == "mon" or day == "tue" or day == "wed":
    total = 10 * tick_Num * 0.75
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "child" and day == "thu" or day == "fri" or day == "sat":
    total = 8 * tick_Num * 1
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "senior"  and day == "thu" or day == "fri" or day == "sat":
    total = 9 * tick_Num * 1
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "general" and day == "thu" or day == "fri" or day == "sat":
    total = 10 * tick_Num * 1
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "child"  and day == "sun":
    total = 8 * tick_Num * 0.9
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "senior" and day == "sun":
    total = 9 * tick_Num * 0.9
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif tick_Type == "general" and day == "sun":
    total = 10 * tick_Num * 0.9
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif day == "mon" or day =="tus" or day == "wed":
    total = 10 * tick_Num * 0.75
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif day == "thu" or day =="fri" or day == "sat":
    total = 10 * tick_Num * 1
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))
elif day == "sun":
    total = 10 * tick_Num * 0.9
    print("Total: $" + format(total,",.2f"))

else:
    print("NO TICKET: invalid day")
```

Comment: what do you mean by "runs incorrectly"?

Comment: @FrankYellin  It ran incorrectly when I input : Senior, 1, mon, 600. It is supposed to not run the first if statement based off of the input but still does for some reason.

Comment: operator precedence ...

Comment: You shouldn't write an `elif` for every possible combination of conditions. You should create dictionaries like `{'child': 8, 'senior': 9, 'general': 10}` and get the factors for the price from there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I identified your problem correctly, your first clause `200 <= m_Time <= 1600 and tick_Type == "child" and day != "sat" or day != "sun"` would always be True if `day != 'sun'` is True because of the way Python calculates booleans. What I believe you want is something like this:

```
if 200 <= m_Time <= 1600 and tick_Type == "child" and day != "sat" and day != "sun":
...
```